# What is proper setup for "anacron"?

Tags: 10.04, 9.10, cron, syslog

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 and 10.04 on MediaTemple (ve) servers.

On both of them, the **anacron** setup is broken, ... and they have been broken since I first installed Ubuntu.  It has only come to my attention recently, when I realize my log files were not rotating.

I am hoping someone who has anacron working can help diagnose the problem and suggest a fix.

Here is **/etc/cron.d/anacron** ...
This part works correctly:  Every morning at 7:30am, **cron** executes this command to start up anacron.

```
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 7    * * *   root    test -x /etc/init.d/anacron && /etc/init.d/anacron start >/dev/null
```

The problem is that **/etc/init.d/anacron start** fails:

```
# /etc/init.d/anacron start >/dev/null
start: Unknown job: anacron
```

Notice that /etc/init.d/anacron is a symbolic link to /lib/init/upstart-job:

```
# ls -l /etc/init.d/anacron
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan 12  2010 /etc/init.d/anacron -> /lib/init/upstart-job
```

Now I am stumped.  Anyone have any suggestions how to fix this?

Take a look in **/var/log** and see if your log files are being rotated (as opposed to growing indefinitely).  If they **are** being rotated, then you probably have a working **anacron**, so please check your setup and let me know how it differs from mine.

Thanks in advance, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this is strange, because since Karmic the **/etc/cron.d/anacron** has looked like this:

```
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

#30 7    * * *   root   test -x /etc/init.d/anacron && /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null
30 7    * * *   root    start -q anacron || :
```

as the job was moved to *upstart*.

Reinstalling `anacron` should then do the job (back up your existing configuration first of course).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Reinstalling anacron didn't fix it, but editing /etc/cron.d/anacron directly did solve the problem.

Comment: For the reinstallation solution to have worked properly, you'd have to use `sudo apt-get purge` instead of `sudo apt-get remove` to remove the configuration files as well. Not removing the config file will make the system use the existing config instead of setting up the default one as the reinstallation was meant to do.